# FireFox and Chrome Interpreting Width differently

Tags: css

I have given width and padding to form fields in percentages. The total width of fields are being interpreted differently in Chrome and in Firefox.

For example at **html{width:980px}**, width of Item1 field **Firefox is 515px**(1+10+493+10+1) whereas in **Chrome its 515.501px** (1+10.266+492.969+10.266+1)

The form can be viewed at
http://cf7trial.project.buzztone.com.au/forms/premium-forms/bogart/

Can anyone help me in understanding and resolve why are widths assigned are being interpreted differently by both the browsers ??? I have witness this problem in other projects as well.

Comment: use everything in relative.that can solve problem.

Comment: What format do you use? The format should be 10.59% not 10.5%

Comment: @Innovation What do you mean?

Comment: Every thing should be in percentage.